# Building an unbroken route between two pixels

Tags: python, image-processing, shortest-path

I have a closed figure of pixels. Pixels with 3 or more neighbors I highlighted in red.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohEYx.png)

My task is to check whether two certain red pixels are connected by black pixels in such a way that there are no other red pixels between these two red pixels.

Right example:
[image: Right example]

Wrong example:
[image: Wrong example]

I have so far the only idea how to solve this problem:
You can take a 3x3 pixel square that will "scan" where to go from one red pixel to another, and if it on the way from one red pixel to another, the square will meet a red pixel, then the program will show that this path is not suitable.

Perhaps this problem can be solved in a simpler way? Or are there some methods, for example, in the OpenCV library, that will make the solution easier and less costly?

Comment: This seems to be not an image processing problem. It can be done with recurent function, that walks around a maze finding if there is a path between two points.

Comment: This is a graph problem. Try DFS or BFS.

Comment: once you know the connectivity of pixels it is a search problem (depth first or breadth first search). When this becomes too expensive there are heuristic based search algorithms like A* (A-Star) and probably others. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm

Comment: if you want to stick to image processing, calculate "connected components", and then check if both pixels are labeled the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the specifics of this problem to your advantage, a few things to consider:

1. If your current node is black, there is always only one way to go next (otherwise the node would be red).
2. If you reached a red node, then you are at a dead end (or at the node you want to get to).
3. There are a maximum of four black paths around the starting node (otherwise it would be too crowded, and some would be red).

So I would just delete all the nodes that are red and are not your starting or end-node (so the surrounding black nodes are dead ends as they should). Then traverse from your start to end, there are a host of algorithms that do that for you, as others pointed out. Otherwise you can consider the 3 "properties" above and build your own algorithm, you'll have 4 paths at most, that you can traverse node by node. The path will never split and finish either at a dead-end or at the end-node.

Comment: There is no need to delete the red nodes. (If you don't know in advance where they are, finding them takes much more work than solving the problem itself.)

Answer (score 0):

From one of the red pixels, follow all connected paths in turn until you reach another red node, and check if that node is the desired target. (There is no need to continue the search from there.)

This seems straightforward.

[image]

In the worst case, the workload is proportional to the sum of the lengths of the paths between the starting point and the related red points, and this is optimal.

In the best case, it is the length of the shortest path between the two given points.